# How do I do a case sensitive rename or move operation in perl?

Tags: perl, case-sensitive

I have a question about renaming a directory in perl (caveat: needs to be a case-sensitive rename).

I have a directory named Demo.  I have a script that renames the directory, but I need it to be case sensitive.

So Demo is NOT the same as demo.

For example, I have a directory named Demo.  I want to rename this to be CLIENT1. My script is called `perlDirRename arg1 arg2`. I want the code to pass if I provide the arguments Demo CLIENT1, and throw an error if I provide the arguments demo CLIENT1

So to recap:

`./perlDirRename Demo CLIENT1` (pass)

`./perlDirRename demo CLIENT1` (fail)

Here is a code snippet:

```
my $from_dir = $ARGV[0];
my $to_dir = $ARGV[1];

if ($from_dir eq $to_dir) {
  print("Arguments cannot be equal!\n");
  exit(1);
}


move("$dirHome/$from_dir", "$dirHome/$to_dir") or die "Move failed: $!";
```

How do I do a case sensitive rename or move operation in perl?

Comment: Due to OS constraints you may need to rename it once to something else, then rename it back to the correct name. `aAaa` and `aaaa` may be considered the same name and a rename operation ends up not doing anything. Try `aAaa` -> `aAaa_` -> `aaaa`.

Comment: Is there a way that I can do a case insensitive search?

Comment: Why not do a case sensitive string comparison before renaming to be sure? Not 100% sure what you're asking for here. Are you saying "reject arguments where the case doesn't match the filename" or "reject input with upper case letters"?

Comment: What OS are you using? And, more importantly, what filesystem?

Answer (score 4):

> needs to be a case-sensitive rename

There is no such thing.

> So Demo is NOT the same as demo.

That depends entirely on the file system you're using. On a case insensitive file system, such as the ones commonly used on Mac OS (APFS) and Windows (NTFS), `Demo` is in fact the same file as `demo`. On a case sensitive file system, `Demo` and `demo` are different.

This is a property of the file system in question, not any particular operation (such as `rename`).

If you want your program to produce an error if the passed in name is not in canonical form (i.e. does not match the displayed case of the filename) even on case insensitive filesystems, you have to get the canonical name yourself and compare them with `eq`. The details depend on your OS.

Answer (score 1):

The entire thing depends on OS. On Windows, it's quite weird. The case composition of the file names is preserved but it is ignored for the search purposes. That produces really strange results: once you have a `File.txt`, you cannot rename it to `file.txt` because for `file.txt` is already in the directory. But if you do `DIR`, it's still `File.txt`

Comment: Re "*once you have a `File.txt`, you cannot rename it to `file.txt`*", [That's not true at all!!!](https://pastebin.com/9w8Tc2gd) You can easily rename it in Explorer ("My Computer" and such) too.

Comment: My experience was with git. I guess it does not apply to more normal circumstances.

Comment: 1) I don't think there's any ports of `git` to Windows. There is `git` for MSYS (a unix emulation environment) and `git` for Cygwin (a unix emulation environment) and of course `git` for Linux run through WSL (a unix emulation), but none for Windows itself as far as I know. 2) [`git` for Cygwin has no problem changing the case of file names either](https://pastebin.com/6CsGSeJL), and I'd be extremely surprised if the other two do. Case-insensitive file systems are common, and not just on Windows machines.

Comment: More importantly, your "answer" doesn't address the question (how rename a file if it's name matches the argument, but fail otherwise)

Comment: There is most certainly the official git for Windows. https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: Despite what the page says, what you linked is git for MSYS. It is not a native port of git; it runs in a unix emulation environment. The point is that emulations can have all kinds of problems, so there could be problems with the emulation. But there isn't any with Cygwin, so I doubt there's one with MSYS. Feel free to prove me wrong. Just follow the same steps I took in "git-bash".